# Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined on implementing d3.js with react-native

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-native

I am trying to implement d3.js in react native, but i am facing issue Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined.
In below code i am trying to change the color and size of circle buy using on-press function over button

Plugin used

npm install d3@v3.5.17

npm install react-native-svg --save

Code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { ScrollView, Button } from 'react-native'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import Svg,{Circle, Path, Rect, Symbol, Text, Use, Defs, Stop} from 'react-native-svg'; 
    import * as d3 from "d3";

    class SVGexample extends Component {
       constructor (props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {}
       }
       renderCricles() {
         var circle = d3.selectAll("Circle"); //Select all circles
         circle.style("fill", "steelblue"); //fill circles with color steelblue
         circle.attr("r", 60); //Change the radius of circle
       }
       render () {
          return (
           <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
           <Svg
                height="500"
                width="500"
            >
                <Circle
                    cx="50"
                    cy="50"
                    r="45"
                    stroke="blue"
                    strokeWidth="2.5"
                    fill="green"
                />
                <Circle
                    cx="150"
                    cy="150"
                    r="45"
                    stroke="blue"
                    strokeWidth="2.5"
                    fill="green"
                />
                <Circle
                    cx="250"
                    cy="250"
                    r="45"
                    stroke="blue"
                    strokeWidth="2.5"
                    fill="green"
                />
                <Rect
                    x="15"
                    y="15"
                    width="70"
                    height="70"
                    stroke="red"
                    strokeWidth="2"
                    fill="yellow"
                />
              </Svg>
              <Button
                onPress={this.renderCricles.bind(this)}
                title="Bind D3"
                color="#32A1FE"
                style={{height: 50}}
              />
          </ScrollView>
        )
      }
    }


    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
     }
    }


    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
      }
    }


    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SVGexample)
```

`

Comment: You've got a backtick`\`` on the line that defines d3 `import * as d3 from "d3";\``