# react-native & d3 selection library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-native

Currently working on a react-native app with live data streaming from a Bluetooth library. Therefore i need a chart that is constantly rendering itself like the example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1642989) (if anyone can suggest a similar library that would be great), 
but the code is written is html & javascript. and because there are conflicts between React & d3 in this case d3.selection library. i try to work my way around it according to [this article](https://medium.com/@Elijah_Meeks/interactive-applications-with-react-d3-f76f7b3ebc71). i try to convert it into react native code but the selection library does not work, and i couldn't find any example using d3.selection in react native. I'm wondering if d3-selection supports react native. and this is the error i got is this.querySelectorAll is not a function, appreciate if anyone can help me out, here is the code i need working.

```
select(node)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(this.props.data)
  .style("fill", "#fe9922")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 25)
  .attr("y", d => this.props.size[1] - yScale(d))
  .attr("height", d => yScale(d))
  .attr("width", 25);
```

Comment: Did you found any solution for mention scenario?? I am also looking for same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713519/cannot-read-property-queryselectorall-of-undefined-on-implementing-d3-with-rea

Comment: i didn't end up using d3 for my project at the end, but afterwards i did some research on react with d3, d3 has two layers, first layer is the math where you set your scales, and the second layer is to manipulate the svg elements in your dom, which does not always work with react, because react renders the dom as well, the work around is use D3 for the math, and pass the function to your graph component and let the graph component  do the render of svg, hence  react-native dont even have a dom to begin with, i think that will be the case as well, try to do some reserch around react and d3.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make d3 work with react-native. one is with react-native ART and other one is with SVG using react-native-svg. For some 3D graph, react-native-svg works better. You use refs attribute in a d3 selection to refer to svg.

Comment: Can you give an example of how the using "refs attribute in a d3 selection to refer to svg" with react-native would work? 

I could _not_ get something working with this. I believe because d3 `select` refers to the dom and the dom does not exist in react-native.